# Get list number for a given element in list of lists

Tags: python

Let's say we have `N` elements from `0` to `N - 1` (`N` is known) scattered into `k` lists as follows:

`X = [[0, 1, 6], [2, 4], [3, 5]]` for `N = 7, k = 3`

Given the number how can I determine the number of the group it is in? For example `1` is in first group and `5` is int the third group.

I can nest loops and check it manually (for each given number check each group where it can be) but how do I do this with more clean and functional-like style in Python? It'd more useful especially when I have list of numbers `[1, 3, 5]` and want to transform it into list of groups of each of elements ie. `[1, 3, 3]`

EDIT:

I was asked to present the way I am doing it now so here it comes:

```
results = []
numbers = [1, 3, 5]
for number in numbers:
    for i in range(len(X)):
        if number in X[i]:
            results.append(i)
```

Comment: How are you doing it right now? Would you share it with us? It is simple and maybe you are already doing it. Its time complexity is < O(n) where n is length of master list.

Comment: Also, defined "more clean". Isn't clean determined by readability, speed and effectiveness? What's the reason and why would you need anything besides nested loops? All functions calls you're trying to fish for, are more or less a loop already, just that you don't see it as such because it's a function call to you probably. But the work you do with nested loops, are 99% of the time the same work wrapped in a function name - if you find "another solution" to your question.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: If you're just doing a single lookup of `X`, then you might as well just do what you're currently doing. But if you need to make multiple lookups, then it's probably worthwhile to transpose the data in `X` so that you can do instant lookups.

Comment: Why when you do the lookups on `[1, 3, 5]` is the expected result `[1, 3, 3]` instead of `[0, 2, 2]`? We normally use zero-based indexing in Python.

Comment: @PM 2Ring Whatever, both are acceptable for me

Comment: Ok. BTW, using scnerd's answer you can do stuff like `a=[1, 3, 5]; b=[X_map.get(u) for u in a]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this without re-computing for every new number you're looking for is to make a dictionary:

```
X = [[0, 1, 6], [2, 4], [3, 5]]
X_map = {element: group for group, elts in enumerate(X) for element in elts}
# {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 0}
```

Now for any given number, just look it up:

```
X_map.get(5, None)  # 2
X_map.get(7, None)  # None
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 [(index, row.index(your_number)) for index, row in enumerate(X) if your_number in row]
```

output:

```
your_number = 1
[(0, 1)]
```

means:
array number 0, index 1